# Memory footprint of C++ functions returning by reference or value?

Tags: c++, function, return-by-reference, return-by-value

I am trying to reduce the memory footprint of an application developed mostly in C++ and one the things I was looking into was returning a particularly large data structure by reference vs returning them by value. I needed some confirmation on it. For instance, say I have member functions in a class `some_object` as follows:

```
const some_type& get_some_type(...) {
   ...;
   return ...;
}
```

vs

```
const some_type get_some_type(...) {
   ...;
   return ...;
}
```

Is my understanding correct that assignment by calling the latter (return by value) would leave two copies of the data `some_type` in memory at certain points during the application's execution, while calling the former (return by reference) avoids this?

Another effort as part of the overall goal of reducing the memory footprint was to change the very definition of `some_type` in a manner that would preclude using the return by reference option above. In such a case, since `some_type` (which is actually a container of sorts, say, of data of type `data_type`) is used inside a loop as follows:

```
const some_type& = some_object->get_some_type(); // returns by ref. a large container
for(...) {
   ...;
   data_type = some_type.at(...);
   ...;
}
```

I assume if we are constrained to use the return by value above, then I would need to make the change as follows by introducing a new function `get_some_type_at` to get an element of the container by value (are there any downsides to doing this that I should be aware of, say, in performance?):

```
for(...) {
   ...;
   data_type = some_object->get_some_type_at(...); // returns by value a small object
   ...;
}
```

Again I am looking mostly for confirmation of these aspects. But details and insights are most appreciated. Thanks for your time and interest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most good compilers implement *return value optimisation*, so you needn't worry about unnecessary construction of copy objects.

Hence, choose

```
some_type get_some_type(...) {
   ...;
   return ...;
}
```

unless you're using an old compiler.

(Acknowledgement to juanchopanza; also drop the const object return; explanation in comments.)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization for more details; pointless to duplicate this here.

Comment: +1, although you probably don't want to return a `const` object. That kills move semantics.

Comment: Actually, every time you can return constant reference, RVO cannot be done, because you can return refernce, if you save object inside class and RVO can be done only if object is a temporary.

Comment: @juanchopanza; very sharp. I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: Didn't know about that - thanks for the helpful reference, @Bathsheba.

Comment: I read on another post that its advisable in some cases to return const even for value; e.g., to do things like if( func() = some_value ).

Answer (score 2):

> Is my understanding correct that assignment by calling the latter (return by value) would leave two copies of the data some_type in memory at certain points during the application's execution, while the calling former (return by reference) avoids this?

With a modern compiler chances of that are pretty slim. The standard specifically blesses what's called return value optimization (and named return value optimization) to let a compiler avoid creating extra copies in a case like this. Every reasonably modern compiler of which I'm aware includes this optimization. In some cases (e.g., gcc) they do this optimization *even* when you tell the compiler *not* to do optimization. With optimization turned on, you'd have to look at something like 10 years (maybe more) to find a compiler that didn't do it.

C++11 adds "move" capability to do even more to ensure against the problem you're concerned with, even when you return a large object by value.

Bottom line: looks to me like what you're looking in the wrong place -- you might want to consider adding an explicit move constructor (and possibly move assignment operator) to your class, but in general, you can just return by value and be happy.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying this applies even to huge containers, e.g., supposing I had a std::map<std::pair<...>, std::vector<...> >? And say the size of the map was >100 million? Its safe to do what I did before entering a loop and according to you, with modern compilers, memory is not duplicated? It would then seem like return by reference is rendered obsolete.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: yes, it'll work even with a huge map. Returning a reference isn't *entirely* obsolete -- things like `iostream`s should still be returned by reference.

Comment: Wow...looks like I am way behind the times. I just looked up move semantics.

Comment: One more clarification, please. I am using gcc-4.1.2 on Linux and MSVC++ 2010; so the RVO would apply for me with those compilers?